# Selenium scrapes only the first item that it finds

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, webdriverwait

I use the following block of code to scrape a website

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Users/USER/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://mamikos.com/cari/ugm/all/bulanan/0-15000000'
driver.get(url)

kamar = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('kost-rc__content')

for desc in kamar :
    nama = desc.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[1]').text
    kecamatan = desc.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[2]').text
    harga = desc.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/span[1]').text
    print(nama, kecamatan, harga)
```

After running it, the output only seems to print the first result of that page. I've tried to change the xpath to this

```
for desc in kamar :
    nama = desc.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="app"]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[1]').text
    kecamatan = desc.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="app"]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[2]').text
    harga = desc.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="app"]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/span[1]').text
    print(nama, kecamatan, harga)
```

But it only gives out an error, please help.

Side note : google chrome Version 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) (64-bit) and driver used was ChromeDriver 95.0.4638.69

Comment: You need to read about xpath and how to write it better.

Comment: but it only gives out an error - what error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scrape the *Name*, *Info* and *Price* information you can use the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

Code Block:

```
driver.get("https://mamikos.com/cari/ugm/all/bulanan/0-15000000")
names = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='kost-rc__info']//span[contains(@class, 'rc-info__name')]")))]
infos = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='kost-rc__info']//span[contains(@class, 'rc-info__location')]")))]
prices = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='rc-price__real']//span[contains(@class, 'rc-price__text')]")))]
for i,j,k in zip(names, infos, prices):
    print(f"Name:{i} Title:{j} Price:{k}")
driver.quit()
```

Console Output:

```
Name:Kost Singgahsini Sakura Karanggayam Sleman Yogyakarta Title:Kecamatan Depok Price:Rp1.370.000
Name:Kost Singgahsini Granada UGM Yogyakarta Title:Kecamatan Depok Price:Rp1.790.000
Name:Kost Kurnia Terban Tipe A UGM Yogyakarta RMZ Title:Kecamatan Gondokusuman Price:Rp606.000
Name:Kost Singgahsini Maleo UGM Kaliurang Yogyakarta Title:Kecamatan Depok Price:Rp1.973.000
Name:Kost AB-AE Tipe B Gejayan Yogyakarta RMZ Title:Depok Price:Rp1.710.000
Name:Kost AB-AE Tipe A Gejayan Yogyakarta RMZ Title:Depok Price:Rp1.425.000
Name:Kost Pogung Familia Tipe C Sleman Yogyakarta RMZ Title:Mlati Price:Rp1.900.000
Name:Kost Pogung Familia Tipe B Sleman Yogyakarta RMZ Title:Mlati Price:Rp1.710.000
Name:Kost Pogung Familia Tipe A Sleman Yogyakarta RMZ Title:Mlati Price:Rp1.425.000
Name:Kost Hanung Tipe B UGM Yogyakarta RMZ Title:Mlati Price:Rp736.000
Name:Kost Apik Tapak Dara Tipe B Deresan Yogyakarta Title:Depok Price:Rp1.620.000
Name:Kost Singgahsini Putri Maoni Tipe A Gejayan Yogyakarta Title:Depok Price:Rp1.520.000
Name:Kost Singgahsini Omah Khiar Tipe F Karang Gayam Yogyakarta Title:Depok Price:Rp1.720.000
Name:Kost Apik Tapak Dara Tipe C Deresan Yogyakarta Title:Kecamatan Depok Price:Rp2.205.000
Name:Kost Singgahsini Putri Maoni Tipe B Gejayan Yogyakarta Title:Depok Price:Rp1.720.000
Name:Kost Wisma Yudhistira Tipe C Mlati Sleman Yogyakarta Title:Mlati Price:Rp2.250.000
Name:Kost Pondok Bugenvil 3 Caturtunggal Depok Sleman Title:Depok Price:Rp1.800.000
Name:Kost Pranasmara 34C Tipe B Depok Sleman Title:Depok Price:Rp1.200.000
Name:Kost Pondok Bugenvil 2 Caturtunggal Depok Sleman Yogyakarta Title:Depok Price:Rp1.800.000
Name:Kost Rahayu Residence Tipe C Depok Sleman Yogyakarta Title:Depok Price:Rp1.150.000
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, helped me a lot. Quick question, do you have any recommendations about where to start learning web scraping using selenium ? since I'm new to this and would like to know the basics before advancing any further with web scraping. Thank you in advance

Comment: The best way is to start with [Frequent 'selenium' Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium?tab=Frequent) within StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code in c# to solve your problem. You can adapt it to your language, especially the xpath part.

```
var els = driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//div[@class='kost-rc__content']"));

foreach(var el in els){
var nama = el.findElement(By.Xpath(".//span[@class='rc-info__name bg-c-text bg-c-text--title-4 ']"));
console.log("nama:"+nama.Text());

var kecamatan = el.findElement(By.Xpath(".//span[@class='rc-info__location bg-c-text bg-c-text--body-1 ']"));
console.log("kecamatan:"+kecamatan.Text());
}
```